# How do I generate a undirected graph in c++?

Tags: c++, kruskals-algorithm

I have to generate simple undirected graph, to test my Kruskal's algorithm on it.
I have a structure for all the connections, made like this:

```
    struct connection
    {
       node1;
       node2;
       edge_value;
    }
```

Now I need to generate a decent amount of these connections, to test Kruskal's on it. The Kruskal's algo wasn't this tough than this generation, maybe because this is the first time I am faced with Graphs.

Comment: I am fairly sure, but because 1 node my have more than one connection that nodes should be pointers to nodes.

Comment: I had to did it this way, it's an assigment.

Comment: @amit: Kruskal's algorithm works by sorting undirected edges by value and then using a UNION-FIND data structure to get the heaviest edges that do not form cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Your data structure is ok, because you want to run the kruskal algorithm!

I assume that you have already the kruskal implementation (with this data-structure, the only thing you need to do is set up a vector and then sort that vector with a proper function and finally walk through that vector, having a computational cost of n log(n) ).

If you need to test your algorithm I will recommend looking into uva's website, from the top of my head I can refer you to this problem: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/113/11354.html You could use the 3 example cases to test if your kruskal implementation works..